# Creating a new record out of a newly created user record

Tags: user-record, create-records

I have a custom object called `Employee__c`. Once I create a new `User` in Salesforce, a new and corresponding `Employee__c` record has to be automatically created in the system using the information from the `User` record.

How can I create a new `Employe__c` record out of a new `User` record?

Comment: Using a trigger, or process builder.

Comment: If your question isn't much deeper than that, I'd recommend going over to Trailhead. [This module on process builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) or [this module on apex triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro) should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, but what the others said.. Process builder or trigger.  I did this in the `after context` so you can link your `Employee__c.User` to it..

```
trigger User on User (after insert)
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();

    for(User u : Trigger.new)
    {
        userList.add(u);
    }

    List<Employee__c> employeeList = new List<Employee__c>();

    for(User user : userList)
    {
        Employee__c emp = new Employee__c();
        emp.User__c = user.ID;
        employeeList.add(emp);
    }

    insert employeeList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Process builder or a trigger to create the Employee records.

Comment: How is your answer different than Derek's?